# Android SQLite onUpgrade migrate data from column A to B while adjusting values

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a column in my table with values in seconds (BIGINT). I need to migrate that data to a new column inside my `SQLiteOpenHelper` `onUpgrade` method, however the data should now be in milliseconds. Is there an easy way to do this with pure SQL? I know I can run `db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET column_b = column_a")` to copy all the values to column_b, however I'm not sure if it is possible to modify the value by either converting seconds to millis or by multiplying seconds value with 1000

Comment: do u check this?! "db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET column_b = column_a * 1000")"

Comment: that's exactly what I'm after - thanks! post it as an answer please and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL query below to change the value:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE table SET column_b = column_a * 1000")
```